# Azure B2C window load event

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have the Custom UI for Azure B2C. I would like to do some actions on window load event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

I tried to implement it in different ways, e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
   console.log('Window loaded');
};
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('Window loaded');
 })
```

However, none of them works. (There is no error, just the 'Window loaded' is not logged)

Is it possible to utilize the window load event on Azure B2C Custom UI? I suspect it may not be possible to use the window load event, because we may not have control over it from the custom UI templates, however I haven't found any confirmation for that.

Comment: Could you please provide the error what you are getting?

Comment: There is no error. Just the 'Window loaded' is not logged in this case

Comment: The engine that serves the custom, self-asserted views appears to use jQuery, so I had to use the document.ready approach.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this can help you

Like you, I needed to do some actions after that the page was loaded.
More precisely, after that the `<div id="API">` was rendered

After trying everything, I found this solution and it works great

```
<script>
   var observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
      var apiElement = document.getElementById('api');
      if (apiElement) {
         init(apiElement);
         observer.disconnect();
      }
   });
   observer.observe(document, { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: false, subtree: true });



   function init(apiElement) {
      // do your stuff here

      console.log("api div is rendered", apiElement);
   }
</script>
```

More info about MutationObserver can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 1):

[Brad C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97946/brad-c) should write this up and get the credit for it.

It's true Azure B2C uses its own custom jQuery lib, so not all of the document.ready methods work as [documented in the standard jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

For example, the docs give this as their first example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

but that didn't work for me. What did work was this:

```
$(function() {
    console.log("The DOM is now loaded");
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because the function would sometimes be called before the actual page content was loaded. In those cases the <body> only contains a <noscript> and <div id="no_cookie">. Specifically this would happen with a script which is added on all b2c pages when switching from one b2c page to another.